# A sumifs in Clojure

Tags: clojure, sumifs

I am trying to do a sumifs (from Excel) in Clojure. I have a csv file which has column size categorized by Big, Medium, Small. And there is another column called as Revenue. What I am trying to do is to sum the revenue for each company by size.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
(math
  sum
    ($for [Size] [row (vals input-data) :let [Size (:Size row)]]
      (+ (:Revenue row) 0 )))
```

This is a fork of Clojure.

Comment: What fork of Clojure are you using? What is `$for`? What is `math`? What is `sum`? These are not standard Clojure functions.

Comment: Not a standard fork of Clojure. The $for works similar to a for statement except the output is in matrix format. What would the code be for a standard clojure output. I can reduce the columns or I can sum the columns but not both

Comment: Um. I recognize `vals` and `+`. What is "matrix format"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a conventional way to do a `sumif` using standard Clojure methods:

```clj
(defn sumif [pred coll]
  (reduce + (filter pred coll)))
```

Here is an example of using `sumif` to sum all odd numbers from 0 to 9:

```
(sumif odd? (range 10)) ; => 25
```

## Update:

But if you want to aggregate your data by `Size`, then you may apply [`fmap` method](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/generic/functor.clj) from [`algo.generic` library](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic) to the results of `group-by` aggregation:

```
(defn aggregate-by [group-key sum-key data]
  (fmap #(reduce + (map sum-key %))
        (group-by group-key data)))
```

Here is an example:

```
(defn aggregate-by [group-key sum-key data]
  (fmap #(reduce + (map sum-key %))
        (group-by group-key data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following, assuming that you have a seq of maps representing your data available:

```
(defn revenue-sum [props]
  (reduce (fn [acc {:keys [size revenue]}]
            (update-in acc
                       [size]
                       #(if % (+ revenue %) revenue)))
          {}
          props))
```